# Which NEMA 17 Stepper Motor for Titan?

Tags: stepper, motor, e3d-titan

I'm trying to find a comparable Nema17 (42BYGHW609) for my new Titan extruder state side with non-month-long shipping from China.

Would this work (and about the same size and weight as the recommended 42BYGHW609)?

- 45 N•cm (63.7 oz•in) holding torque
- NEMA 17 bipolar 1.65"x1.65"x1.57" 4-wire
- 1.8° step angle (200 steps/rev)
- Rated current 2 A & resistance 1.1 Ω

Candidates:

- [Nema Size 17 Stepper Motor Bipolar 45Ncm (64oz.in) 2A 42x40mm 4 Wires w/ 1m Cable & Connector for DIY 3D Printer CNC Rob](https://www.oyostepper.com/goods-45-Nema-Size-17-Stepper-Motor-Bipolar-45Ncm-64ozin-2A-42x40mm-4-Wires-w-1m-Cable-Connector.html)
- [Nema 17 Stepper Motor 1.5A 12V 63.74oz.in 4-Lead 39mm Body W/ 1m Cable and Connector for DIY CNC/ 3D Printer/Extruder](https://www.oyostepper.com/goods-493-Nema-17-Stepper-Motor-15A-12V-6374ozin-4-Lead-39mm-Body-W-1m-Cable-and-Connector-for-DIY-CNC-3D-PrinterExtruder-.html)

Comment: The answer to this question can be found by looking up the specs of the older stepper and compare these with the potential replacement. Furthermore [this may be of help](https://reprap.org/wiki/NEMA_17_Stepper_motor).

Comment: That extruder should work fine. It's even a bit overkill.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a product recommendation question.

Comment: Hi gujimeili3, this question was put on hold. In essence we cannot help you with finding suppliers that are faster. That said, nema 17s are ultra common and you can probably next day order this from many large company websites, if not pick it up from local stores. Also if its not the Exact one for this extruder, it wont matter, you will calibrate it anyways.

Comment: Yes, it is a product question, but it is more closely a component question.  The OP isn't asking which motor company makes better motors.  This is more like "can I use a 1/2 W wirewound resistor, or am I better with a 1 W carbon composition resistor".

Comment: See meta question [Why was this (stepper motor selection) question deemed “off topic”?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-was-this-stepper-motor-selection-question-deemed-off-topic)

Answer (score 2):

The safest thing to do is to wait a month (it probably won't take that long anyway), and order the correct stepper motor from China, or pay more and locally source the 42BYGHW609.

The 42BYGHW609 is a commonly used stepper and it is best to keep *all* of the steppers matched - just for ease of calibration, matched performance/behaviour, and future maintainability.

Otherwise you need to match (at least) the torque, the inductance, the rated current and resistance of the coils, if not the physical size and the stepping angle. Which is not an impossible task, but a bit of a pain, TBH.

The time that you spend verifying the various steppers and then re-checking and worrying would be better spent ordering the correct one in the first place and waiting for it to arrive.

BTW, take a look at the [RepRapWiki - Nema 17](https://reprap.org/wiki/NEMA_17_Stepper_motor) page which lists suitable stepper motors.

---

As an aside, if this is your first purchase from China and are worried about reliability of service, then don't. I order everything from China, and haven't had a problem. In addition, if you order via eBay/PayPal you are financially protected if your order doesn't arrive (which does sometimes happen), or, alternatively, order from AliExpress, where I have never had something not arrive (if that makes sense)

---

I have just realised that you need an extruder replacement (and not a X/Y/Z stepper)... in which case, as [towe states](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11371/which-nema-17-stepper-motor-for-titan#comment20737_11371), either of your candidates is probably fine, although maybe over-torqued (slightly).

However, I, personally, would still replace the stepper with the same model that the 3D printer originally came with, but that is just my personal preference - unless you had found the 42BYGHW609 to be not strong enough, and you actually *want to up the torque*..?